# how to iterate on a table in sql server for the same id in many rows?

Tags: sql-server, loops, iterator

I have a table called `city` and table called `routes_`.
the relation between them is many to many so i used a table called `map` between them.
`routes_` table has the names of the routes
`city` table has the cordinates of city.
`map` table has all the cities for each route with its order in the route:

```
CREATE TABLE city
(
   ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY not null  , 
    name varchar(50) UNIQUE,
    populationOfCity int  not null,
    center char (10) not null,
    gover_id  int null,
    cordinates geography null,
);

CREATE TABLE routes_
(
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY not null,
    name varchar (50) not null,
);

CREATE TABLE map
(
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY not null  , 
    orderOfcity int not null,
    city_id int not null,
    route_id int not null,
    FOREIGN KEY( city_id )REFERENCES city (id),
    FOREIGN KEY( route_id )REFERENCES routes_ (id)
);
```

I need to find the longest route.
I write this algorithm to find it but actually i am totally new for the syntax of sql server so i need some help writing it

1. I used the geography type to find the distance between two cities using `stdDistance`.
2. I want to `group by` the map table by the route_id so i group the cities for each route
3. order the map table by the `orederOfcity` to calculate the distance
4. iterate on the map table after it's grouped and ordered and go in a loop to find the distance for each route while it's the same route_id
5. save the distance of each root in an array and then find the max.

I started writing this but i didn't know how to complete with the loop syntax

```
 SELECT map.route_id FROM map group by map.route_id order by MIN(map.orderOfcity)  

  declare @i int 
  declare @numOfRows int 
  set @i=1
  set @numOfRows=(SELECT COUNT (*) from map )
  while @i<@numOfRows
```

this is insert statements of the tabels: 
insert cities :

```
INSERT INTO city (name,populationOfCity,cordinates,center)
VALUES ('Damascus',3140000,geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(0.0275361 51.5064694)', 4326),'yes');


INSERT INTO city (name,populationOfCity,cordinates,center)
VALUES ('Alepo',3140000,geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(-66.1711278 -17.4125)', 4326),'Yes');

INSERT INTO city (name,populationOfCity,cordinates,center)
VALUES ('Hama',725000, geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(036.6666667 35.0833333)', 4326),'yes');

INSERT INTO city (name,populationOfCity,cordinates,center)
VALUES ('Homs',1033000, geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(036.7500000 34.6666667)', 4326),'yes');

INSERT INTO city (name,populationOfCity,cordinates,center)
VALUES ('Latakia',554000, geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(035.7500000 35.5000000)', 4326),'yes');

INSERT INTO city (name,populationOfCity,cordinates,center)
VALUES ('Tartus',393054, geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(035.9166667 34.9166667)', 4326),'yes');


INSERT INTO city (name,populationOfCity,cordinates,center,gover_id)
VALUES ('Al_Bab',20000, geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(037.4833333 36.3833333)', 4326),'No',2);

INSERT INTO city (name,populationOfCity,cordinates,center)
VALUES ('Afrin',24000, geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(036.8333333 36.5333333)', 4326),'No');


INSERT INTO city (name,populationOfCity,cordinates,center)
VALUES ('As Safirah',14000, geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(037.3500000 36.0833333)', 4326),'No');


INSERT INTO city (name,populationOfCity,cordinates,center)
VALUES ('Manbij',26000, geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(037.9500000 36.5166667)', 4326),'No');


INSERT INTO city (name,populationOfCity,cordinates,center)
VALUES ('Azaz',34000, geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(037.0666667   36.6000000)', 4326),'No');
```

insert routes :

```
INSERT INTO routes_(name) VALUES ('Al_Bab___Afrin');
INSERT INTO routes_(name) VALUES ('As Safirah___Azaz');
INSERT INTO routes_(name) VALUES ('Damascus___Latakia');
INSERT INTO routes_(name) VALUES ('Tartous___Damascus');
```

insert maps:

```
INSERT INTO map(orderOfcity,city_id,route_id) VALUES (1,7,1);
INSERT INTO map(orderOfcity,city_id,route_id) VALUES (2,9,1);
INSERT INTO map(orderOfcity,city_id,route_id) VALUES (3,8,1);

----As Safirah___Azaz
INSERT INTO map(orderOfcity,city_id,route_id) VALUES (1,9,2);
INSERT INTO map(orderOfcity,city_id,route_id) VALUES (2,8,2);
INSERT INTO map(orderOfcity,city_id,route_id) VALUES (3,10,2);
INSERT INTO map(orderOfcity,city_id,route_id) VALUES (4,11,2);



INSERT INTO map(orderOfcity,city_id,route_id) VALUES (1,6,4);
INSERT INTO map(orderOfcity,city_id,route_id) VALUES (2,4,4);
INSERT INTO map(orderOfcity,city_id,route_id) VALUES (3,6,4);
```

the iteration must be on the table of map after i group it by routes_id and order it bu orderOfCity, so i know the cities of each route, and then i should calculate the distance of each group, to do that i should iterate on the map table and calculate distance between cities depending on having the same route_id 
if have this example in routes: 
1)Al_Bab___Afrin
2)As Safirah___Azaz'
in map its cities are :
al bab, As Safirah,Afrin
 this cities in map have the routes_id =1 
so i should calculate the distance between them
and then move to the next route_id in mab which is 2 and make the same calculation of its cities.

Comment: post the sample output what you want

Comment: and some sample data for us to work with

Comment: @ZoharPeled we both are asking the same sample data and required output

Comment: @mohan111 you wrote sample output, if it wasn't clear to me I'm guessing it will also be not clear to niha.

Comment: i edited and added my inserted data is that useful?

Comment: @nihagave sample data to populate data all your tables.but what you want where the iteration need to be done ..still unclear

Comment: can u read the last edit please.

Comment: In general, in SQL, we try to write queries that deal with *sets*, rather than writing loops. We also don't try to break things down into separate steps - we try to formulate a query that describes that entire end result we want and then let the server work out *how to do it*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this using a JOIN to consecutive rows in the MAP table:

```
SELECT R.Name as RouteName,
        SUM(C.cordinates.STDistance(C2.cordinates)) As Distance
FROM routes_ R
INNER JOIN Map M
    ON M.route_id = R.Id
INNER JOIN City C
    ON M.city_id = C.ID
INNER JOIN Map M2
    ON M2.route_id = R.Id AND M2.orderOfcity = M.orderOfcity + 1
INNER JOIN City C2
    ON C2.Id = M2.city_id
GROUP BY R.Name
```

This gives:

```
RouteName          Distance
---------          --------------------------
Al_Bab___Afrin     103547.016615796
As Safirah___Azaz  247811.559896733
Tartous___Damascus 162303.402745115
```

To retrieve just the longest route use:

```
SELECT TOP 1 R.Name as RouteName,
        SUM(C.cordinates.STDistance(C2.cordinates)) As Distance
FROM routes_ R
INNER JOIN Map M
    ON M.route_id = R.Id
INNER JOIN City C
    ON M.city_id = C.ID
INNER JOIN Map M2
    ON M2.route_id = R.Id AND M2.orderOfcity = M.orderOfcity + 1
INNER JOIN City C2
    ON C2.Id = M2.city_id
GROUP BY R.Name
ORDER BY SUM(C.cordinates.STDistance(C2.cordinates)) DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`LEAD()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx) to get the next `cordinates` in a given route. you can then use [`STDistance`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/bb933952.aspx) between `cordinates` and next cordinates to find the distance between two cities in a route. 
Use CTE or a derived query to `GROUP BY Route.ID` and do a `SUM(Distance of cordinates)`.

Something like this

**Query**

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
SELECT R.ID,
cordinates.STDistance(LEAD(cordinates)OVER(PARTITION BY r.id ORDER BY orderOfcity ASC)) as Distance
FROM city c
INNER JOIN map m on c.id = m.city_id
INNER JOIN routes_ r on r.id = m.route_id
)
SELECT TOP 1 ID,SUM(Distance)
FROM CTE 
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY SUM(Distance) DESC
```

**Output**

```
2   247811.559896733
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b983b/1)